# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.thucydides.core.model.TestStep.getStartTime()Ljava/time/ZonedDateTime

Tags: serenity-bdd, reportportal

I recently was able to integrate my BDD cucumber framework with Report Portal.

I run my tests in Circle CI.

Now, what happening is Serenity BDD cucumber tests are appearing blank. I found that it is happening due to below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.thucydides.core.model.TestStep.getStartTime()Ljava/time/ZonedDateTime;
        at com.github.invictum.reportportal.recorder.BddDataDriven.record(BddDataDriven.java:30)
        at com.github.invictum.reportportal.ReportPortalListener.testFinished(ReportPortalListener.java:51)
        at net.thucydides.core.steps.StepEventBus.testFinished(StepEventBus.java:256)
        at net.serenitybdd.cucumber.SerenityReporter.result(SerenityReporter.java:611)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:40)
        at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:16)
        at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:34)
        at cucumber.runtime.RuntimeOptions$1.invoke(RuntimeOptions.java:294)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21.result(Unknown Source)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.JUnitReporter.result(JUnitReporter.java:121)
        at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:310)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
        at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:102)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
        at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:95)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:38)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

This error goes away if I comment out below ReportPortal and BDD reports also start appearing in Circle CI, but then report portal has no reports (obviously because I have commented its core dependency)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.invictum</groupId>
    <artifactId>serenity-reportportal-integration</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.8</version>
</dependency>
```

It looks like both of these will not work together.

I am using these dependencies for serenity.

```
<!--        // net.serenity-bdd serenity-core-->
        <serenity.version>1.2.4</serenity.version>
        <serenity.maven.version>1.2.4</serenity.maven.version>
<!--        // net.serenity-bdd serenity-cucumber-->
        <serenity.cucumber.version>1.1.27</serenity.cucumber.version>
```

What can I do so that both will work together?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue but not using cucumber at all. For me this issue started happening when I moved my project to Java 17 and updated serenity maven plugin to 3.6.23

The problem here is that https://github.com/Invictum/serenity-reportportal-integration has no activity since August 2021 so it looks like it has no support for newer versions.